# Can I use an A record for my application in cloudbees?

Tags: cloudbees

If I have an application on cloudbees, it typically has a URL like:

http://app.account.cloudbees.net

I want to have a top level domain point to it (e.g. www.myapp.com) - but I can only put in A records for that with my DNS provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(A more complete answer here http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Custom+Application+Domains)

A quick way for this is to look up the IP for the A record for your applications name:

```
nslookup app.account.cloudbees.net
```

Then use the IP address that this resolves to. This IP address is fixed.

A better approach is to use a domain alias service like DNS simple (in which case you can keep using a CNAME). See more on the wiki http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Custom+Application+Domains